# How to implement a web that update when you modify it

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, html

I am trying to make a web project where you can modify a web and the others that are seeing the same web will update automatically. I think that the good way is using AJAX, but I am not sure at all if there is an easy way or tool for implement it. If you know any tools, post or methods to develop it I will apreciate it, thanks.

PD: I know that it is possible, I am only looking if there are tools for do the work more easy.

Comment: Take a look at web frameworks? http://memeburn.com/2011/06/32-web-frameworks-to-choose-from-for-your-next-project/

Comment: @epascarello What is this? A spider forum?

Comment: You're probably looking for something like Node.js: http://nodejs.org/

Comment: @epascarello: `web`site me thinks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to do AJAX is using some JavaScript Frameworks like jQuery, Senscha etc...
They will make your life easier while dealing with AJAX requests.
Also don't forget about WebSockets, they allow asychronous communication over a TCP socket, and you can achieve the same effect with WebSockets.

I would recommend you to go with [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) and their AJAX library.
Check tutorial [here](http://learn.jquery.com/ajax/)!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any tools, but you will probably run into problems if you allow more than 1 editor at a time.

Most apps use some kind of [locking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locking_%28computer_science%29) mechanism to prohibit multiple users from editing the same resource.

You should read:

- https://drive.googleblog.com/2010/09/whats-different-about-new-google-docs_21.html
- https://drive.googleblog.com/2010/09/whats-different-about-new-google-docs_22.html
- https://drive.googleblog.com/2010/09/whats-different-about-new-google-docs.html

to learn how google docs implemented real-time collaboration, where multiple users can edit the same document.